# Count letters in text

Tags: python

I have text file as follows...

s1

> MPPRRSIVEVKVLDVQKRRVPNKHYVYIIRVTWSSGATEAIYRRYSKFFDLQMQMLDKFP
>   MEGGQKDPKQRIIPFLPGKILFRRSHIRDVAVKRLIPIDEYCKALIQLPPYISQCDEVLQ
>   FFETRPEDLNPPKEEHIGKKKSGNDPTSVDPMVLEQYVVVADYQKQESSEISLSVGQVVD

s2

> MAEVRKFTKRLSKPGTAAELRQSVSEAVRGSVVLEKAKLVEPLDYENVITQRKTQIYSDP
>   LRDLLMFPMEDISISVIGRQRRTVQSTVPEDAEKRAQSLFVKECIKTYSTDWHVVNYKYE
>   DFSGDFRMLPCKSLRPEKIPNHVFEIDEDCEKDEDSSSLCSQKGGVIKQGWLHKANVNST

.
.
.

I wanted to count letter 'P' in each sequences output should be

>
s1:10

>
s2:20

To acheive this python script as follows

```
infile=open("file1.txt",'r')

out=open("file2.csv",'w')

for line in infile:

     line = line.strip("\n")

   if line.startswith('>'):

        name=line

   else:

        pattern = line.count('P') 

        print '%s:%s' %(name,pattern)

        out.write('%s:%s\n' %(name,pattern))
```

it read line and gives result as follows

>
s1:2

>
s1:3

>
s1:5

>
s2:10

>
s2:10

But i except out put as follows

>
s1:10

>
s2:20
.
.
.

Can any body help how to do this...

Thanks in Advance
Ni

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed, or what about it is not a real question -- Other than bad formatting, and not tagging it as homework (which isn't required, even if it's preferred / recommended) what's wrong with it?

Comment: Agree with agf, the question looks fine really.

Comment: Agree with agf that it looks like an acceptable question.  Disagree with SlapShot that a homework assignment should be answered with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total = 0
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    if line.startswith('>'):
        name = line
    else:
        pattern = line.count('P') 
        total += pattern
        print '%s:%s' %(name,pattern)

#this goes outside the for loop
out.write('%s:%s\n' %(name,total))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse the file line by line. Just iterate over the entire file character by character counting occurrances of the character you are looking for.